# Unable to load packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I was trying to install `lubridate` package but cannot manage to load it to my library

Here are the errors I got.

```
install.packages("lubridate")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/YingHaw/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/lubridate_1.3.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 664643 bytes (649 KB)
opened URL
downloaded 649 KB
package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\YingHaw\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4KMRy3\downloaded_packages


library(lubridate)
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/YingHaw/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/R/Rcpp.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lubridate’
```

I don't understand why I am having this problem.

Comment: *cannot open file 'C:/Users/YingHaw/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/R/Rcpp.rdb': No such file or directory*  Do you have package `Rcpp` installed?

Comment: I always recommend `install.packages("lubridate", dependencies = TRUE)`, to download and install the dependencies at the same time.

Comment: Pascal and Richard are right: **lubridate** needs **Rcpp** but the latter is not installed. Doing as Pascal suggests should take care of installing Rcpp and any other required packages. Not sure why it didn't do it by default though.

Comment: As a clarification, I want to add that the issue is not absence of Rcpp, I currently have the same error and installing Rcpp is by itself problematic, too. Even if you manage to install packages most probably due to the R version it is unable to load later.